# How to do a partial search on a row key in azure table storage?

Tags: node.js, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am using Azure table storage along with node js for a ticketing app.  I am using the client's name as a partition key and ticket id as a row key. 
For example:

`RowKey: {'_': 232344}`

I want the row key to be a combination of ticketid and customer's phone number.  Ex:

`RowKey: {'_': 232344_9393944392} or RowKey: {'_': 2323449393944392}`

and be able to do a partial search on row key using the customer's phone number and retrieve all tickets raised by a customer.
How can I do it in node js?

The following code is how I am querying table storage.

```
const azure = require('azure-storage');
const query = new azure.TableQuery().where('PartitionKey eq ?',client).and('Rowkey eq?',ticketId);
```

This is where I am stuck as I do not how to do a partial search on the row key.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to query entities whose RowKey start with "232344"? If so, you can use filter "RowKey ge '232344' and RowKey lt '232345'" to achieve the goal.

Comment: No, I want to query using phone number "9393944392", so that I could be able to retrieve all the tickets raised by a single customer using their phone numbers. Like the starting part, "232344" will be increased by 1 every time a customer raises a ticket.

Comment: What about having phone number as PartitionKey so your requirement can be converted into partition scan? If you still want Ticket Id as PartitionKey, I'd suggest RowKey format to be "PhoneNumber_TicketId", then the filter string can be "RowKey ge '9393944392' and RowKey lt '9393944393'". Please note that the query will be full table scan since no PartitionKey is filtered in the string.

Comment: Okay, that would work fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've added it as answer, could you please accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions:

- Use Phone Number rather than Ticket Id as PartitionKey. If so, searching a phone number among tickets can be converted into a simple partition scan. This is a more efficient way.
- Keep using Ticket Id as PartitionKey, and use RowKey format `PhoneNumber_TicketId`. If so, searching a phone number among tickets can be converted to a filter string such as `RowKey ge '9393944392' and RowKey lt '9393944393'`, which is a full table scan since no PartitionKey is filtered in the string. This is a less efficient way since full table scan happens.